# Bulding an Angular App in Sharepoint to Display User Office 365-hosted Email

Tags: angularjs, azure, sharepoint, office365, office365api

We're building our first Angular app in order to access our Office 365-hosted mail and display it inside an on-premises Sharepoint 2013 portal, which has an ADFS login that also logins users into Office 365. We've set up our app in Azure AD and have it working (we can pull down data), but are stuck on the single sign-on part. Logged in users are getting asked to sign in (to the app) after they are already signed in to Sharepoint (and previously accepted permissions of course). Our app is based on the Angular app here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/getting-started-Office-365-APIs

Thoughts?

Comment: Any ideas? Shouldn't be so hard to have a user log in to on-premise Sharepoint and see with Office 365 mail with out multiple sign ins (i.e. SSO), with on premise AD synced with Azure AD. C'mon Microsoft, make your stuff work together, not against each other.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it covers 2 kind of SSO: Microsoft Azure AD - SSO and AD FS - SSO.

**Microsoft Azure AD - SSO:**

[image]

When a user access another web app which is also secure by cloud identity servcie, the step 4 and step 5 will not be required (user do not need to fill the user name and password again - cookie based).

**Secure Cloud Service with AD FS:**
[image]

If you have integrated your AD FS with Office 365 cloud service, when enter the user name user_name@your_domain.com, Azure AD with redirect you to the ADFS login page. After user entering the correct user name and password, AD FS will return a token (SAML) which will submit to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf. Then the cloud identity service will issue an new token to sign in the Office 365 service.

**On-premise Service**

For the on-premise service, it is secured by the AD FS directly, which means it does not request a token from Cloud Identity Service, so the Azure AD - SSO will not work in this scenario. In this case, the end user require to sign into the cloud service at once.

Comment: How do I configure the app so users are not presented with a second login screen when they access the app?

Comment: Currently, I'm not able to find a workaround. The possible way is redirect user to ADFS login page directly (user do not need to log in again since he/she has already signed the on-premise service), then use the SAML to obtain the id_token, but I can not make it work so far.

Comment: Thanks for your info and efforts, Jeffrey - much appreciated! Any thoughts on other ways we might make this work? We just need our ADFS/Sharepoint logged in users to see their Office 365 mail.